# How to prevent eventLog file of Spark stream jobs eating up space?

Tags: apache-spark

We have multiple run-forever streaming jobs generating huge eventLogs. These in-progress logs won't be removed until reach the the max age config (spark.history.fs.cleaner.maxAge).

Based on the Spark source code, "Only completed applications older than the specified max age will be deleted." https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a45647746d1efb90cb8bc142c2ef110a0db9bc9f/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/history/FsHistoryProvider.scala

So, in-progress eventLog will never be removed before completion and they are eating up space. Anyone have idea how to prevent it?

We have option like  script periodically removes old files, but it will be our last resort, and we cannot modify the source code, but configuration.